# Django rest framework + cpanel's application manager(phusion passenger) = error 500

Tags: python, django, rest, http-status-code-500, phusion

I'm able to run a local server with the quickstart example from https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/, but after deploy with Application Manager (Phussion Passenger) the
server only display the following page: [no css, js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjesM.png)

And console:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AW6AL.png)

When click /users : [Server error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ghhqo.png)

I did run python manage.py collectstatic

Setup:

1. Centos 7.9
2. Cpanel
3. Application Manager (Phusion Passenger) - Development = True
4. Python 3.8 venv
5. Django + Django Rest Framework - Debug = True

Settings.py :

```py
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'secret'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'tutorial.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'tutorial.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/labdiariocom/testeapi/tutorial/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10
}
```

### Update

I was able to make the api to run using nginx

Comment: Hi, have you solved this issue? Can you explain what you do to make it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello @nzf this error may be occurred because of `STATIC_ROOT` you give static path to your

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/labdiariocom/testeapi/tutorial/static'
```

try to give like this
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static_cdn'

Comment: Hello @Ankit Tiwari, thanks for the response. I deleted the static folder and tested the suggestion with collectstatic, it populated the folder, but the error remains.